# Apresentar resultado de subquery e usá-lo para cálculo

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Eu preciso apresentar um resultado de uma subquery e utilizar o mesmo resultado para realizar um cálculo, é possível jogá-lo para uma variável no MS SQL 2008 ou algo nesse sentido?
exemplo:

```
SELECT
    @test = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [tableTest] WHERE [tableTest].[columnA] = [tableA].[columnA]) as 'Counter'
    , (@test * 50) as 'Calc'
    , [tableA].[columnA]
FROM tableA
```

Comment: Minha pergunta foi respondida na versão em inglês:
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783554/mssql-subquery-result-to-show-and-calculate/>

Comment: E recebeu uma resposta parecida em português também! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma [CTE (Common Table Expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175972%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
WITH CounterTable(columnA, Counter) AS
( 
    SELECT [tableTest].[columnA], COUNT(*) FROM [tableTest] 
    WHERE [tableTest].[columnA] = [tableA].[columnA]
) 
SELECT Counter, columnA, Counter * 50 AS Calc
FROM CounterTable;
```

Usar um `INNER JOIN` pode deixar sua query mais legível

```
WITH CounterTable(columnA, Counter) AS
( 
    SELECT [tableTest].[columnA], COUNT(*) 
    FROM [tableTest] 
    INNER JOIN [tableA] ON [tableTest].[columnA] = [tableA].[columnA]
) 
SELECT Counter, columnA, Counter * 50 AS Calc
FROM CounterTable;
```